# How can i start apache tika in console without open the GUI?

Tags: macos, bash, console, command-line-interface, apache-tika

If i start apache tika in console (OSX):

```
 java -jar tika-app-1.2.jar --text  ~/Downloads/example.pdf
```

The GUI (org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI in menuline) will be always shown in foreground and after process finished it closed.

If processed many files in a loop, then the computer "blocks" respectively the tika process comes again and again into the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Tika should only open the GUI if you start it with the `--gui` flag, or without any flags at all. Passing in `--text` should force it to run command line only

I've just checked with several files, and as expected `--text` never launches the GUI

Have you perhaps been customising Tika? I'd suggest you take a clean build / download from the website, and use that, then ask for advice on the Tika-Dev list about how your customisations are breaking things. (They really shouldn't, so you must be doing something fairly unusual!)

Comment: This is not correct, i think. The `--text` flag means the extracting text from file:

`-t  or --text          Output plain text content`

The binary was download direct from eztika project homepage:

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/tika/tika-app-1.2.jar

Comment: The `--text` flag should preclude any of the GUI code running. You should probably ask on the Tika-Dev list, and explain exactly what you're doing, as what you report shouldn't happen...

Answer (score 1):

Use  `-Djava.awt.headless=true` when running the tika jar.

e.g.:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/tika/1.5/libexec/tika-app-1.5.jar foo.pdf
```